# Интерполяция внутри кода js

Tags: javascript, интерполяция

Есть функция, внутри которой из объекта на веб-страницу вставляется значение. Нужно, чтобы в "warrior.name" часть "warrior" бралась из переменной s. То есть, если s будет "paladin", то функция должна выдать "paladin.name".
p.s. нужно это сделать без использования фреймворков.

```
let s = "warrior";

function warr() {
  document.getElementById("roleTitle").innerHTML = warrior.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ответ нашелся методом тыка. Оказалось, что всего-лишь нужно было убрать скобки в `let s = "warrior";`

```
let s = warrior;

function warr() {
  document.getElementById("roleTitle").innerHTML = s.name;
```

Comment: а где в `let s = "warrior";` скобки, которые нужно было убрать? Добавь в ответ пример готового кода

Comment: это будет работать, только если у тебя есть переменные `warrior`, `paladin` и т.д. Лучше обращаться к ним не через глобальную переменную `s`, а передавать параметром в метод `warr`

Comment: Согласен. В итоге, я так и сделал. Спасибо за совет.